# Recommended rocksdb.Options for storing numpy array in a rocksdb database

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, rocksdb

I want to store numpy arrays in a python version of [rocksdb](https://github.com/lbryio/lbry-rocksdb) database. They have shape (c,h,w) (usually c=10,h=w=512) and dtype np.float32. I don't know how to optimize the various Options (for fast read/write) for the byte size of these objects, e.g. (these are some recommended defaults from [python-rocksdb](https://rocksdb-tina.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html#open)

```
import rocksdb
opts = rocksdb.Options()                        
opts.max_open_files = 3e+5        # In bytes
opts.write_buffer_size = 67108864 # In bytes
opts.max_write_buffer_number = 30 
opts.target_file_size_base = 67108864 # In bytes
```

What would be the best options in terms of read/write speed for numpy arrays? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The defaults are good enough for the vast majority of use cases.

Nobody can give you the options for your app - you have to measure and figure them out yourself

Nonetheless, these are what I recommend

```
  val filter = BloomFilter(10.0)
  val lruCache = LRUCache(8192)
  val blockBasedTableConfig = BlockBasedTableConfig().setCacheIndexAndFilterBlocks(true)
    .setEnableIndexCompression(true)
    .setPinTopLevelIndexAndFilter(true)
    .setPinL0FilterAndIndexBlocksInCache(true)
    .setOptimizeFiltersForMemory(true)
    .setBlockCache(lruCache)
    .setFilterPolicy(filter)

  val options = Options().setCreateIfMissing(true)
    .setEnablePipelinedWrite(true)
    .setAllowConcurrentMemtableWrite(true)
    .setIncreaseParallelism(2 * Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
    .setMaxSubcompactions(4)
    .setMaxBackgroundJobs(2 * Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
    .setCompressionType(CompressionType.LZ4_COMPRESSION)
    .setCompactionStyle(CompactionStyle.LEVEL)
    .setTableFormatConfig(blockBasedTableConfig)
    .setMaxOpenFiles(-1)
    .setMergeOperator(UInt64AddOperator())
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Asad. When you say measure, does it mean that the byte size of objects to be stored relates to these options? Or I need to experiment with various values and test (benchmark) what gives me optimum loading time, irrespective of object type size (hyper parameter search)?

Comment: You should do both. It is a lot of work and will depend on how in depth you want to go. This is in python so you are starting behind the 8th ball anyway